# AutoHotKey Right+Left Click Binding

Tags: click, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, key-bindings

I want the "Up" arrow key to be pressed, but only if both left & right click are held down, and similarly release it when either mouse button is released.  I've been searching for a while but I'm not really familiar with AutoHotKey.

I've tried many things, but here is a basic example (without the release part):

```
 Lbutton & Rbutton::Send {Up}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hotkey below allows for either Right or Left mouse buttons to be pressed first, while retaining their normal functionality.

```
~LButton & ~RButton::
~RButton & ~LButton::
    While GetKeyState("LButton", "P") and GetKeyState("RButton", "P")
        Send, {Up Down}
    Send, {Up Up}
    Return
```